# Displaying image with users product post information?

Tags: php, image

Im making a website like craigslist where people can make a posting of something they want to sell with a post title, post description, and email.

The problem:
I can pull all data from the db except for the image. When images are uploaded they are stored in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploads and the imagename is saved in the database with the rest of the info. Below is my php. Im trying to pull the name of the image from the db and use that to grab it like this

```
echo "<img src='uploads/".$image."' width='200'> ";
```

Im new to php so any tips are appreciated. Is this an ok method to store/retrieve user uploaded images?
Thanks

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; /* Host name */
$user = "root"; /* User */
$password = ""; /* Password */
$dbname = "mydb"; /* Database name */

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql= "SELECT * FROM products";
$result = $con->query($sql);
$image = "SELECT image FROM products";


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<img src='uploads/".$image."' width='200'> ";
        echo "Title: " . $row["title"]. " Price: $" . $row["price"]. " <br> " . $row["description"]. " <br> " . $row["contact"] . " <br><br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$con->close();


?>
```

Comment: Image find url in uploads folder it means uploads folder location in your project or website root folder

Comment: You aren't iterating over image, you have fetched all the values of image field from db and are just using it like raw data. You need to iterate over image. Or why now use $row['image'] instead of $image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use row same for image like:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM products";
$result = $con->query($sql);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<img src='uploads/".$row["image"]."' width='200'> ";
        echo "Title: " . $row["title"]. " Price: $" . $row["price"]. " <br> " . $row["description"]. " <br> " . $row["contact"] . " <br><br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$con->close();
```